# Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cors

I get a 500 server error while I'm try to use `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` in an `.htaccess` file.

Server log says:

```
Invalid command 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

How can I solve this problem? If anyone have some idea please help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line below works for me in the vhost file located there :

*/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts/xxxx.conf*

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

The command to add to your apache config file is:

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"`

You might also want to add:

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` 
(depend on your requirement)

if you get `Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled...` message when restarting apache, you will need to enable `headers` mod by:

`sudo a2enmod headers`